# Cant get SSL working. Apache2/Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

I bought a wildcard SSL certificate from ssl2buy.com but im strugling to get it to work. I cant get my webserver to start up with SSL enabled. My conf file for the website and the error codes from the log file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:433>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/rajohan/ssl/rajohan.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/rajohan/ssl/rajohan.key
    SSLCertificateFile /home/rajohan/ssl/rajohaninter.crt
    ServerName rajohan.no   
    ServerAdmin mail@rajohan.no
    DocumentRoot /var/www/rajohan.no/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


[Sun Dec 10 22:32:56.352511 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 17713] AH02579: Init: Private key not found
[Sun Dec 10 22:32:56.352545 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 17713] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Sun Dec 10 22:32:56.352553 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 17713] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Sun Dec 10 22:32:56.352558 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 17713] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Sun Dec 10 22:32:56.352563 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 17713] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)
[Sun Dec 10 22:32:56.352569 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 17713] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Sun Dec 10 22:32:56.352574 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 17713] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Sun Dec 10 22:32:56.352579 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 17713] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
[Sun Dec 10 22:32:56.352582 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 17713] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
[Sun Dec 10 22:32:56.352584 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 17713] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key rajohan.no:443:1, check /home/rajohan/ssl/rajohaninter.crt
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unhappy to hear that you are experiencing troubleshoots with SSL certificate installation process. There can be an issue with your `SSLCertificateChainFile`, Please follow below instructions to install SSL on Apache HTTP Server.

https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/install-ssl-certificate-in-apache-server

https://support.globalsign.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1225234-apache-http-server---ssl-certificate-installation